# Add module positions in Opencart 2.0.0.0 version

Tags: module, opencart, opencart2.x

I wanted to create additional module position in this version 2.0.0.0 of Opencart, so I came across this tutorial which worked fine, but some how the title of the position will not show under the drop down for selecting a new position. I can see a space where the title should be but there is nothing there, and regardless it works if I select the blank space it select the position I created.

What could I be missing that the title to the new position is not showing?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

admin/view/template/design/layout_form.tpl add your new position in this select tag

```
<select name="layout_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][position]">
```

and also in this method at the bottom of the file

```
function addModule() {
```

And then you have to add a template and a controller in catalog/view/theme/default/template/common you can use the same code as it is in content_top.php & content_top.tpl, just rename the file as your new position name.

And then in Home controller or any other page where this position is required, you have to add

```
$data['new_position'] = $this->load->controller('common/new_position');
```

After adding it to controller, you need to add it to the template files. Add to all the page templates you want to show the custom position on.

For example, to show the position on the home page, you'll add  to catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/home.tpl

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////